# Matlab, "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to generate a RGB label slice using label2rgb and use it to update a RGB volume, like this:

```
    labelRGB_slice=label2rgb(handles.label(:,:,handles.current_slice_z), 'jet', [0 0 0]);


    handles.labelRGB(:,:,handles.current_slice_z) = labelRGB_slice;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
**Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts**

Error in Tesis_GUI>drawSeedButton_Callback (line 468)
        handles.labelRGB(:,:,handles.current_slice_z) = labelRGB_slice;
```

When debugging I get this:

```
size(labelRGB_slice)

ans =

   160   216     3

K>> size(handles.labelRGB(:,:,handles.current_slice_z) )

ans =

   160   216
```

I declared handles.labelRGB like this:

```
handles.labelRGB = zeros(dim(1), dim(2), dim(3), 3);
```

So I don't understand the index disparity.

**How can I make the slice assignment work?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the way you have declared `handles.labelRGB` it is a 4D array of size `[160 216 3 3]` however you are indexing it as a 3D array using `handles.labelRGB(:,:,handles.current_slice_z)` that means matlab will use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html#f1-86862) for the last two dimensions. So if, say `handles.current_slice_z = 5`, it returns `handles.labelRGB(:,:,2,2)` which is a matrix of size `[160 216]`. So depending on the meaning of `handles.current_slice_z` you either need to use

```
handles.labelRGB(:,:,:,handles.current_slice_z) = labelRGB_slice;
```

or

```
handles.labelRGB(:,:,handles.current_slice_z,:) = labelRGB_slice;
```

Comment: The first option 

        handles.labelRGB(:,:,:, handles.current_slice_z) = labelRGB_slice;

gives "subscripted assignment dimension mismatch".

The second option

handles.labelRGB(:,:,handles.current_slice_z,:) = labelRGB_slice;

works fine. Thanks